# Jasmine stubRequest is not sending the string as passed

Tags: javascript, json, jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine and I have the following code:

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest(url).andReturn({
                        "status": 200,
                        "contentType": 'text/json',
                        "responseText": '{"entities": [1]}'
            });
```

And the client code has line like this:

```
JSON.parse(response);
```

where `response` is `'{"entities": [1]}'`. But when running jasmine sends the response as :

```
Object{entities: [1]} //  console.log(response)
```

and hence the `parse` fails in client code with exception:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object" in client.js
```

Why the string is getting corrupted? How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the code you can see on mock-ajax line 267 :

```
responseValue: function() {
    switch(this.responseType) {
      case null:
      case "":
      case "text":
        return this.readyState >= 3 ? this.responseText : "";
      case "json":
        return JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      case "arraybuffer":
        throw unconvertibleResponseTypeMessage('arraybuffer');
      case "blob":
        throw unconvertibleResponseTypeMessage('blob');
      case "document":
        return this.responseXML;
    }
```

It seems that in the case of json jasmine mock-ajax allready parse the object.

So I'm guessing that if you remove the content type, you will have the exact string you set in responseText in the first place :

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest(url).andReturn({
                    "status": 200,
                    "responseText": '{"entities": [1]}'
        });
```

Didn't knew of mock-ajax, may use it soon, thanks.